# Reading secrets from kubernetes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, environment-variables, openshift

I've set an env variable in openshift that I need to be read from my project in Spring:

The env variable is set like this in the yaml file:

```
     env:
       - name: PRIVATE_KEY
         valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:
             name: jwt-signing-keys
             key: private-key
```

On the other hand I've set up the same in my application.properties file as follows:

```
example.private-key=${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Last but not least, the code to read this key is:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtKeyProvider {

    private final ResourceUtil resourceUtil;
    private final Base64Util base64Util;

    @Value("${example.private-key}")
    private String key;

    @Getter
    private PrivateKey privateKey;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        privateKey = readKey(
                 key,
                "PRIVATE",
                this::privateKeySpec,
                this::privateKeyGenerator
        );
    }

    private <T extends Key> T readKey(String resourcePath, String headerSpec, Function<String, EncodedKeySpec> keySpec, BiFunction<KeyFactory, EncodedKeySpec, T> keyGenerator) {
        try {
            String keyString = resourceUtil.asString(resourcePath);
            //TODO you can check the headers and throw an exception here if you want

            keyString = keyString
                    .replace("-----BEGIN " + headerSpec + " KEY-----", "")
                    .replace("-----END " + headerSpec + " KEY-----", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            return keyGenerator.apply(KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"), keySpec.apply(keyString));
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
            throw new JwtInitializationException(e);
        }
    }

    private EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec(String data) {
        return new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(base64Util.decode(data));
    }

    private PrivateKey privateKeyGenerator(KeyFactory kf, EncodedKeySpec spec) {
        try {
            return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        } catch(InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new JwtInitializationException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any issue but for some reason this it's not working. I know the code works because the PK was read from the resource folder but now that I've set this as an env variable I don't know whay it's not working.

Any idea??

**UPDATE:**
The private key I want to access was mounted in a volume like this, so at the end all I want is to access from my code in spring to that Data private key field.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
When running my app I get this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'PRIVATE_KEY' in value "${PRIVATE_KEY}"
```

I don't think my error is in the code actually but maybe in the kubernetes configuration. Should I add something else?

Comment: It may sound silly, but did you check the spacing in YAML file? `valueFrom` and `name` should be on the same indentation level.

Comment: Yes, it was just an error when pasting. It's OK in the yaml.

Comment: Can you specify, how did you create secret along with sample command and config?

Comment: It was created by someone else and mounted in a volume, but now I need to access it.

Comment: Check you Chelm configuration. Spring reads environment variable, so Chelm  must convert you secret into environment variable inside the container first. Seems like you have a secret, but no environment variable.

Comment: Sorry, but what is Chelm?